# Android Studio not showing support library in project explorer

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an Android app targeting SDK19 built in Android Studio.
In Project Structure>App>Dependencies I added:  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'

This then showed up in the app build.gradle file as:

```
dependencies {
    provided 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
}
```

However it does not show up under the Project Explorer>External Libraries tab.

Under the External Libraries tab  there is "Android API 19 Platform" , "1.8"  and "support-v4-19.0.1"

I thought the  appcompat-v7 library would show up as an external library in the project explorer.  Why doesn't this show up there?  Thanks.